# Decision tree classifier,multilabel output

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

Decision Tree supports multi label classification right? my `y` labels are of type `[['brufen','amoxil'],['brufen'],['xanex']]`. Now `y` labels can be of the type `list of list of labels` as mentioned in the sklearn documentation, so why does it gives me error of unknown label type?

This error is resolved in a way that the length of list should be consistent, but how else should I handle this problem apart from one hot encoding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the labels to label-indicator format first. Then you can use them with decision trees.

For converting, you can use [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

y_converted = mlb.fit_transform([['brufen','amoxil'], ['brufen'], ['xanex']])
# Output: array([[1, 1, 0],
#                [0, 1, 0],
#                [0, 0, 1]])

mlb.classes_
# OutPut: array(['amoxil', 'brufen', 'xanex'], dtype=object)
```

Now use this `y_converted` instead of original `y` in decision tree.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutputclassifier

You can use `sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier` with a decision tree to get multi-label behavior. If I understand correctly, it works by internally creating a separate tree for each label.